# How can i to get access to variables from kv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I developing a game in which there are buttons and each has its own id. I want to give them the same functions using the for loop in the py file, but despite the correct connection it says that the variable was not found. how can I access these variables?

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen    
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

    


Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1280')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')

class Main_screen(Screen):
    pass
        
class Store_screen(Screen):
    for elps in [btn_1, btn_2, btn_3, btn_4, btn_5, btn_6, btn_7, btn_8]:
        .......
        ..........
class Screen_manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
cnct = Builder.load_file('Hang.kv') 

class HangApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return cnct
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    HangApp().run()





Button: 
        
    id: btn_1

        
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,1
        Line:
            width: 4
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height              
        Image:
            id: unequiped_1
            source: 'C:/*****/****/OneDrive/Рабочий 
                           стол/ellipses/equiped_ellipse_1.png'             
            size: 250, 250
            
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esgF6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you have to add "<Store_Screen>:" above the "Button:" in the .kv-file. You also have to define the button beneath the class and connect it:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6w3L.png)

I hope this helps because this is how I use buttons in .py and .kv files.